# Count all occurences in a table with mulptiple columns (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that has partner id followed by multiple column combinations. My task is to count how many partners, each of those combinations have.

Here is an example of a table I'm working with:

[image]

And here is what I am looking to do:

[image]

Does anyone knows how to sort this out?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  MAX(COMB_1) AS COMB_1,
  MAX(COMB_2) AS COMB_2,
  MAX(COMB_3) AS COMB_3,
  MAX(CATEGORY) AS CATEGORY,
  COUNT(*) AS PARTNER_COUNT
FROM NoOneNamesTheirTableInSQLQuestions
GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(';', COMB_1, COMB_2, COMB_3);
```

This uses a MySQL function `CONCAT_WS()`, but there should be equivalent ways of doing this in each of the other databases you tagged your question: Oracle and SQLite.

Comment: Hi @Bill, thank you for your solution! It suited well to what I need in a real scenario. And sorry for forgeting about the table name lol.